# React Native + Expo trying to import custom fonts but error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to import custom fonts to React Native using the Expo framework but I get an error:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Layout`., 
    in Layout
    in Unknown (created by Route())
    in Route (created by Route())
    in LocationProvider (created by Route())
    in Route() (created by RootRoute)
    in RootRoute (created by ContextNavigator)
...
```

Here's my code. It tells me to check the export, but it looks like it's exporting alright (I'm using _layout.js):

```js
import { Stack, NavigationContainer } from 'expo-router';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { Provider } from '../hook/context/auth';
import { LoginPage } from './(auth)/login';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function Layout(){
    const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        'DMBold': require('../assets/fonts/DMSans-Bold.ttf'),
        'DMMedium': require('../assets/fonts/DMSans-Medium.ttf'),
        'DMRegular': require('../assets/fonts/DMSans-Regular.ttf'),
    })

    const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async() => {
        if(fontsLoaded){
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync()
        }
    }, [fontsLoaded])

    if(!fontsLoaded){
        return null; // load splash screen
    }

    return (
    <Provider>
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginPage} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
    )
}
```

I'm pretty sure I have the relative path right:
[image: Visualize some of the project structure]

Comment: Can you console log the `fontsLoaded` right after importing the fonts? Also make sure the font files arent corrupted.

Comment: @MoinulHaq this is my output:
`false`
`true`

Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Layout`., 
    in Layout
    in Unknown (created by Route())
    in Route (created by Route())
    in LocationProvider (created by Route())

Comment: Also, I open up the fonts in OpenType and they appear to be fine.

Comment: Can you share the `LoginPage`, seems like the issue is from there. The issue might be with the export of LoginPage.

Answer (score 0):

This error message might be related to your imports, not the fonts.
Either a component might not be properly exported or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
export default function LoginPage() {}

import LoginPage from './(auth)/login';

// OR

export function LoginPage() {}

import { LoginPage } from './(auth)/login';
```

Depending on the above